# Shell magic wanted: format output of hexdump in a pipe

Tags: perl, shell, formatting, netcat, hexdump

I'm debugging the output of a program that transmits data via TCP. 
For debugging purposes i've replaced the receiving program with `netcat` and `hexdump`:

```
netcat -l -p 1234 | hexdump -C
```

That outputs all data as a nice hexdump, almost like I want. Now the data is transmitted in fixed blocks which lengths are not multiples of 16, leading to shifted lines in the output that make spotting differences a bit difficult:

```
00000000  50 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |P...............|
00000010  00 50 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.P..............|
00000020  00 00 50 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..P.............|
```

How do I reformat the output so that after 17 bytes a new line is started?
It should look something like this:

```
50 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |P...............|
00                                                |.               |
50 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |P...............|
00                                                |.               |
50 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |P...............|
00                                                |.               |
```

Using hexdumps `-n` parameter does not work since it will exit after reaching the number of bytes. (Unless there is a way to keep the netcat programm running and seamlessly piping the next bytes to a new instance of hexdump).

Also it would be great if I could use `watch -d` on the output to get a highlight of changes between lines.

Comment: The hex part would be enough.

Comment: Did you read all about the format options on the hexdump man page ? It looks like you should be able to easily do what you want...

Comment: I added the "perl" tag for you, those people will probably eat this up and you have Perl kicking around, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For hexdump without characters part.

`hexdump -e '16/1 "%0.2x " "\n" 1/1 "%0.2x " "\n"'`

Answer (score 3):

I use this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use bytes;

my $N = $ARGV[0];

$/ = \$N;

while (<STDIN>) {
    my @bytes = unpack("C*", $_);
    my $clean = $_;
    $clean =~ s/[[:^print:]]/./g;
    print join(' ', map {sprintf("%2x", $_)} @bytes),
    "  |", $clean, "|\n";
}
```

Run it as `perl scriptname.pl N` where N is the number of bytes in each chunk you want.

Answer (score 2):

also you can use [`xxd -p`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_xxd.htm) to make a hexdump .